# How to Read (query) embedded resource Access file. (VB.NET, Microsoft Access)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing an application, but I have a big question and I don't know if is possible.
Is possible to embed an Access file(mdb) in the VB.NET solution (Resources) and do an a query and get data?

If the answer is yes, please guide me to develop this, if not, please tell me why not possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is sort of but not really. the whole point of resources is that they are data compiled into your assembly. They are not discrete files so, in your case, there is no database file to connect to in order to execute a query. What you can do is extract the resource and save the data as a file, then use that file like you would any other. If appropriate, you can then delete that file when you're done with it.

Here's an example of how you might load data from a database file that is part of your project/application:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filePath = "|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdb"

    DataGridView1.DataSource = GetPeople(filePath)
End Sub

Private Function GetPeople(filePath As String) As DataTable
    Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0", .DataSource = filePath}

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString),
          command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Person", connection)
        connection.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim table As New DataTable

            table.Load(reader)

            Return table
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Here's how you might do something similar if you had loaded the data file into your application resources:

```vb
Private databaseFilePath As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    databaseFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName()

    File.WriteAllBytes(databaseFilePath, My.Resources.Database1)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = GetPeople(databaseFilePath)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    File.Delete(databaseFilePath)
End Sub

Private Function GetPeople(filePath As String) As DataTable
    Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0", .DataSource = filePath}

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString),
          command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Person", connection)
        connection.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim table As New DataTable

            table.Load(reader)

            Return table
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Note that the method to load the data into a `DataTable` hasn't changed. Also, the code makes use of temp file functionality built into Windows and .NET. You should use that functionality for files that you're just using temporarily and you should endeavour to delete them when you're done with them, as demonstrated here.

Comment: @LARC, I have updated the answer with code examples. I strongly recommend that you take a look as you may still learn something useful.